# Не выводит число

Tags: sql, sql-server

Привет всем. У меня такая проблема...
есть запрос в котором я считаю заправки и т.д... 1-е  4-ре пункта выводятся нормально а последний выводит нули. почему

это верхушка запроса

```
date,
sum(Zapravka) as Zapravka,
sum(MoveToZapravka) as MoveToZapravka,
sum(Cou) as Cou,
SUM(Cou)/SUM(Zapravka) * 100 as persent
```

и вот результат

```
  date              Zapravka  MoveToZapravka Cou  persent
2015-05-15 00:00:00.000 70      58           35     0
2015-05-16 00:00:00.000 94      86           61     0
2015-05-17 00:00:00.000 106    100           64     0
2015-05-18 00:00:00.000 109     85           70     0
2015-05-19 00:00:00.000 101     83           55     0
2015-05-20 00:00:00.000 112     78           66     0
```

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста  (SQL Server 2008 R2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените это:

```
SUM(Cou)/SUM(Zapravka) * 100 as persent
```

на это:

```
SUM(Cou + 0.0)/SUM(Zapravka + 0.0) * 100 as persent
```

Comment: Большое человеческое спасибо!

Comment: @FastTI если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: "минус" за решение без объяснения.

Comment: @KromStern можете тогда и себе поставить минус за ответ без объяснения, например тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448086/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-opengl-es-2-0-gl-framebuffer-incomplete-attachment/448088#448088

Comment: @null спасибо за совет, ответ по ссылке исправил ) Давайте и ваш ответ улучшим - напишем почему `+ 0.0` может помочь

Comment: @KromStern я к тому что прежде чем кого-то поучать необходимо у самого навести порядок в этом вопросе. В чужом глазу сучок видим, а в своем бревна не замечаем.

Comment: @null это неконструктивно. А вот вы мне указали на соринку, я у себя исправил.

Comment: @null Не поймите меня неверно. Я бы сам рад предложить правку к вашему ответу, но к сожалению не владею тонкостями SQL в достаточной мере, чтобы быть уверенным в своей попытке его объяснения.

Comment: @KromStern Как раз для таких вещей и существуют комментарии, чтобы если что-то не совсем понятно можно было спросить, а не минусовать! Автор вопроса принял ответ и ничего не спрашивал - значит ему все понятно, если вам что-то непонятно - задайте вопрос в комментарии, не нужно стесняться!

Comment: @null я исхожу из того, что вопрос и ответ должны быть полезны не только автору, но и остальным 32+ людям которые их увидели и увидят в будущем. Развернутые ответы для того и пишутся, чтобы не заставлять вытягивать информацию по крупицам из ответившего. Также, не стоит забывать, что сегодня вы есть на ресурсе, а завтра вас может не быть, и ответить на комментарий будет некому. Больше тратить время не буду, не хотите сделать лучше - ваше право.

Answer (score 2):

Учите матчасть про деление int на int, особенно про то, что результатом такого действа также является целое число, а остаток отбрасывается.

Вы делите меньшее число SUM(Cou) на большее SUM(Zapravka), получаете ноль и умножаете на 100. Внимание вопрос: что получится, если ноль умножить на сто?

Comment: логично)) спасибо за ликбез