# Ошибка OpenGL ES 2.0 - GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT

Tags: java, android, opengl, gles2.0

Начал изучать тени, решил использовать для начало теневую карту. Написал такой код для создания нового буфера кадра который будет рисовать в текстуру только буфер глубины.

```
    // Создаем новую текстуру
    int i[] = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, i,0);
    m_shadowMap = i[0];
    if (m_shadowMap == 0) Log.e("genTexture","m_shadowMap = "+m_shadowMap);
    // Связываю текстуру  с 2D текстурой
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_shadowMap);
    // заполняю текстуру в формате буфера глубены
    GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height, 0, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, null);
    // Фильтры
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    // Cоздаем буффер кадра
    GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, i, 0);
    m_fbo = i[0];
    if (m_fbo == 0) Log.e("genTexture","m_fbo = "+m_fbo);
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_fbo);
    // Указываю буфферу кадра что бы рисовал в текстуру только буффер глубены
    GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_shadowMap, 0);

    int Status = GLES20.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER);

    // >!!!< Тут выходит ошибка: GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT
    if (Status != GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE ) {
        Log.e("genTexture","GL_FRAMEBUFFER error: "+Status);
        Log.e("genTexture","width: "+width+"  height: "+height);
    }
```

Когда вместо `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16` поставил `GL_RGBA`, вместо `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT` поставил `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` - работает.

Объясните из за чего ошибка и что конкретно значит?

Comment: В место GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16 поставил GL_RGBA, в место GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT поставил GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0. Работает.

Comment: Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заработало! Причем ничего не менял. не знаю почему заработало.

Comment: Может что-то неочевидное поменяли? Сбросили кеш какой-нибудь...

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать разбиндить текстуру (`glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0)`) перед тем как работать с буфером (`glFramebufferTexture2D(...)`). Читал что у кого-то были с этим проблемы. Но гарантировать, что это поможет - не могу.

Comment: Ничего не изменилось. Та же ошибка.